# Nullspace of matrix with Cosine

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a question. I consider following matrix:

```
A = {{1, 0}, {0, Cos[b]}}
```

and i would like to find its nullspace. If b=Pi/2, rank of A is 1 and then I can calculate its nullspace.
However, if I write matrix A in the above-mentioned symbolic form, Mathematica returns that nullspace does not exist.
How can I solve this problem?

How can I ask to Mathematica, for what values of b nullspace of A is not empty?

Answer (score 3):

Yeah, symbolic computations in Mathematica are usually performed for generic choices of values for the symbols. But `Eigensystem` can help here:

```
{eigenvalues,eigenvectors} = Eigensystem[A]
```

> {{1, Cos[b]}, {{1, 0}, {0, 1}}}

Now you can see: If `Cos[b] == 0` then `{0, 1}` lies in the null space of `A`.

Comment: Uha, thanks @MichaelE2!

Comment: Is it possible to ask to mathematica for what values of b the rank of matrix A is equal to 1?

Comment: The matrix `A` has rank `1` if precisely one element of `eigenvalues`  is nonzero. In the case of a 2 by 2 matrix, Mathematica can be asked like this: `Reduce[Or @@ Thread[eigenvalues == 0], b]`